# same random number every time in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the rand() function in c++, but it returns the same random number every time.

I have put the statement `srand(unsigned int(time(0)));` in the very first line of the main function, yet I am still having this problem.

I have Googled the problem and have found several answers on this site, but they all suggest putting the `srand()` statement in the first line of the main function, which I have done.

Is there someone who can help me figure out this problem?  Thanks.

EDITED @5:10pm:

The program is a complicated one.  I've tried to troubleshoot and here is some additional information:

the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(0));
    std::auto_ptr<simulation> sim_ptr;
    const double delta_t = 0.000002;
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Error: invalid number of arguments specified" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "--random") == 0) {
        sim_ptr = std::auto_ptr<simulation>(create_random_simulation(delta_t));
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "--naive") == 0) {
        const double alpha = 1000;
        sim_ptr = std::auto_ptr<simulation>(create_naive_simulation(delta_t, alpha));
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "--tree") == 0) {
        const double alpha = 1000;
        sim_ptr = std::auto_ptr<simulation>(create_tree_simulation(delta_t, alpha));
    }

    const size_t time_steps = 200;
    const size_t particles_count = 2048;
    const size_t particles_shown = 2048;
    const size_t image_width = 512;
    const size_t image_height = 512;

    std::valarray<double> m  = random_valarray(particles_count);
    m = m * m * m;
    std::valarray<double> x  = random_valarray(particles_count);
    std::valarray<double> y  = random_valarray(particles_count);
    std::valarray<double> vx, vy;
    vx.resize(particles_count);
    vy.resize(particles_count);
    std::cout << "Simulation" << std::endl;
    for (size_t time_step = 1; time_step <= time_steps; time_step++) {
        std::cout << "\tFrame " << time_step << " / " << time_steps << std::endl;
        sim_ptr->step(x, y, vx, vy, m);
        std::vector<uint8_t> image;
        image.resize(image_width * image_height);
        for (size_t particle = 0; particle < particles_shown; particle++) {
            const uint8_t color = ((particle * 23297) % 255) + 1;
            draw_particle(x[particle], y[particle], m[particle], &image[0], image_width, image_height, color);
        }
        const std::string image_path = get_image_path(time_step);
        write_bmp_image(image_path, &image[0], image_width, image_height);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the class function that calls the rand() that is zero every time:

```
void random_simulation::step(std::valarray<double>& x, std::valarray<double>& y,
    std::valarray<double>& vx, std::valarray<double>& vy,
    std::valarray<double>& m) const
{
    const size_t particles_count = x.size();
    assert(particles_count == y.size());
    assert(particles_count == vx.size());
    assert(particles_count == vy.size());

    const double tau = 2.0 * sqrt(2.0 * this->delta_t);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < particles_count; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i] + tau * (((rand() % 2001 - 1000)/2000));
        y[i] = y[i] + tau * (((rand() % 2001 - 1000)/2000));
        if (i == 1){
            std::cout << x[i] << " ";
            std::cout << y[i] << " ";
        }

    }
}

simulation* create_random_simulation(double delta_t) {
    return new random_simulation(delta_t);
}
```

According to the loop, `x[i]` and `y[i]` should change with each iteration, but they remain the same with each iteration.

Comment: Is that the *only* place you put it? An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would really help.

Comment: If you have C++11 support available, don't use `rand()` at first place.

Comment: @LihO, Even pre-C++11 has Boost's Random library.

Comment: yes, I just did a search for "srand" and it returned only once instance, in line 52 of the main function.

Comment: Could it be that you run the executable in a loop, so that the it is still the same second on the clock?

Comment: @Kay: I've posted 'main' function above, there doesn't appear to be a loop

Comment: If you execute the file using a script to get multiple results, you might execute the file multiple times in one wallclock second. That is a **very** common problem in the usage of `srand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(rand() % 2001 - 1000)/2000
```

It's always `0`. You can divide it by `2000.0` have values between `[0.0, 1.0)`

---

You can use C++11 random utilities, for example [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution):

```
std::default_random_engine generator(time(0));
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);

double x = distribution(generator);
```

Comment: yes, why is it always zero?  I had the same code in a separate program and it gave me a random number between -0.5 and 0.5.

Comment: @user2826735: It is zero because it uses integer arithmetic. It cannot possibly give you a random number "between -0.5 and 0.5". So no, in your "separate program" the code was different. In your "separate program" you used floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @AndreyT: Sorry if I'm being a n00b.  The original code was this: 'x[i] = x[i] + tau*(drand48() - 0.5);' . How do I replicate this without using 'drand()'?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following in XCode and it produced a different random number each time (using C++ static cast)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    int r = rand();

    std::cout << "Random number: " << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

// Random numbers:
// 2064544746
// 2064897693
// 2065132991
// 2065250640
```

Using Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler on i386 x86_64 architecture

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that when using `rand()` one must have a call to `srand()` at some point in the beginning of their program to ensure different pseudo-random numbers each run. However, the correct usage is:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

`time(0)` returns 0, which seeds `rand()` the same way each run, causing your issue. `time(NULL)` returns whatever is stored in the memory where time points and will properly seed the generator.

Comment: 0 works fine as a null pointer. Not that I'm advocating either when there's `nullptr`.

Comment: `NULL` evaluates to zero. There's no difference between them.